# Are codatatypes really terminal algebras?

Tags: haskell, type-systems, category-theory, coinduction

(Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure how codatatype works, especially when not referring to terminal algebras).

Consider the "category of types", something like [Hask](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask) but with whatever adjustment that fits the discussion. Within such a category, it is said that (1) the initial algebras define datatypes, and (2) terminal algebras define codatatypes.

I'm struggling to convince myself of (2).

Consider the functor `T(t) = 1 + a * t`. I agree that the initial `T`-algebra is well-defined and indeed defines `[a]`, the list of `a`. By definition, the initial `T`-algebra is a type `X` together with a function `f :: 1+a*X -> X`, such that for any other type `Y` and function `g :: 1+a*Y -> Y`, there is exactly one function `m :: X -> Y` such that `m . f = g . T(m)` (where `.` denotes the function combination operator as in Haskell). With `f` interpreted as the list constructor(s), `g` the initial value and the step function, and `T(m)` the recursion operation, the equation essentially asserts the unique existance of the function `m` given any initial value and any step function defined in `g`, which necessitates an underlying well-behaved `fold` together with the underlying type, the list of `a`.

For example, `g :: Unit + (a, Nat) -> Nat` could be `() -> 0 | (_,n) -> n+1`, in which case `m` defines the length function, or `g` could be `() -> 0 | (_,n) -> 0`, then `m` defines a constant zero function. An important fact here is that, for whatever `g`, `m` can always be uniquely defined, just as `fold` does not impose any contraint on its arguments and always produce a unique well-defined result.

This does not seem to hold for terminal algebras.

Consider the same functor `T` defined above. The definition of the terminal `T`-algebra is the same as the initial one, except that `m` is now of type `X -> Y` and the equation now becomes `m . g = f . T(m)`. It is said that this should define a potentially infinite list.

I agree that this is sometimes true. For example, when `g :: Unit + (Unit, Int) -> Int` is defined as `() -> 0 | (_,n) -> n+1` like before, `m` then behaves such that `m(0) = ()` and `m(n+1) = Cons () m(n)`. For non-negative `n`, `m(n)` should be a finite list of units. For any negative `n`, `m(n)` should be of infinite length. It can be verified that the equation above holds for such `g` and `m`.

With any of the two following modified definition of `g`, however, I don't see any well-defined `m` anymore.

First, when `g` is again `() -> 0 | (_,n) -> n+1` but is of type `g :: Unit + (Bool, Int) -> Int`, `m` must satisfy that `m(g((b,i))) = Cons b m(g(i))`, which means that the result depends on `b`. But this is impossible, because `m(g((b,i)))` is really just `m(i+1)` which has no mentioning of `b` whatsoever, so the equation is not well-defined.

Second, when `g` is again of type `g :: Unit + (Unit, Int) -> Int` but is defined as the constant zero function `g _ = 0`, `m` must satisfy that `m(g(())) = Nil` and `m(g(((),i))) = Cons () m(g(i))`, which are contradictory because their left hand sides are the same, both being `m(0)`, while the right hand sides are never the same.

In summary, there are `T`-algebras that have no morphism into the supposed terminal `T`-algebra, which implies that the terminal `T`-algebra does not exist. The theoretical modeling of the codatatype Stream (or infinite list), if any, cannot be based on the nonexistant terminal algebra of the functor `T(t) = 1 + a * t`.

Many thanks to any hint of any flaw in the story above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> (2) terminal algebras define codatatypes.

This is not right, codatatypes are terminal *coalgebras*. For your `T` functor, a coalgebra is a type `x` together with `f :: x -> T x`. A `T`-coalgebra morphism between `(x1, f1)` and `(x2, f2)` is a `g :: x1 -> x2` such  that `fmap g . f1 = f2 . g`. Using this definition, the terminal `T`-algebra defines the possibly infinite lists (so-called "colists"), and the terminality is witnessed by the `unfold` function:

```
unfold :: (x -> Unit + (a, x)) -> x -> Colist a
```

Note though that a terminal `T`-algebra does exist: it is simply the `Unit` type together with the constant function `T Unit -> Unit` (and this works as a terminal algebra for any `T`). But this is not very interesting for writing programs.

Answer (score 8):

> it is said that (1) the initial algebras define datatypes, and (2) terminal algebras define codatatypes.

On the second point, it is actually said that terminal **coalgebras** define codatatypes.

A datatype `t` is defined by its constructors and a fold.

- Constructors can be modelled by an algebra `F t -> t` (for example, the Peano constructors `O : nat` `S : Nat -> Nat` are collected as a single function `in : Unit + Nat -> Nat`).
- The fold then gives the catamorphism `fold f : t -> x` for any algebra `f : F x -> x` (for nats, `fold : ((Unit + x) -> x) -> Nat -> x`).

A codatatype `t` is defined by its destructors and an unfold.

- Destructors can be modelled by a coalgebra `t -> F t` (for example, streams have two destructors `head : Stream a -> a` and `tail : Stream a -> Stream a`, and they are collected as a single function `out : Stream a -> a * Stream a`).
- The unfold then gives the anamorphism `unfold f : x -> t` for any coalgebra `f : x -> F x` (for streams, `unfold : (x -> a * x) -> x -> Stream a`).

Answer (score 8):

> (Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure how codatatype works, especially when not referring to terminal algebras).

A codata type, or coinductive data type, is just one defined by its *eliminations* rather than its *introductions*.

It seems that sometimes *terminal algebra* is used (very confusingly) to refer to a *final coalgebra*, which is what actually defines a codata type.

> Consider the same functor T defined above. The definition of the terminal T-algebra is the same as the initial one, except that m is now of type X -> Y and the equation now becomes m . g = f . T(m). It is said that this should define a potentially infinite list.

So I think this is where you’ve gone wrong: “*m* ∘ *g* = *f* ∘ *T*(*m*)” should be reversed, and read “*T*(*m*) ∘ *f* = *g* ∘ *m*”. That is, the final coalgebra is defined by a carrier set *S* and a map *g* : *S* → *T*(*S*) such that for any other coalgebra (*R*, *f* : *R* → *T*(*R*)) there is a unique map *m* : *R* → *S* such that *T*(*m*) ∘ *f* = *g* ∘ *m*.

*m* is uniquely defined recursively by the map that returns `Left ()` whenever *f* maps to `Left ()`, and `Right (x, m xs)` whenever *f* maps to `Right (x, xs)`, i.e. it’s the assignment of the coalgebra to its unique morphism to the final coalgebra, and denotes the unique anamorphism/unfold of this type, which should be easy to convince yourself is in fact a possibly-empty & possibly-infinite stream.